# Floated side-by-side elements that drop to their own row when not enough space

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside another div that are at 50% width. I have a minimum width set on these divs so that when the page width gets too small, they no longer sit side-by-side and stack vertically instead. I'd like a pure CSS solution, if possible, to make it so the inner divs have 100% width as soon as they separate into their own rows.

I made a code snippet to illustrate what I mean:

```css
#container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.width-50 {
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="width-50 yellow">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div class="width-50 red">
    Div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

If you grab the resize handle and shrink the width of the parent div, eventually the divs don't have room to stack side-by-side, but they don't fill in the full width of the parent div.

Comment: Use a media query

Comment: use flexbox you don't need media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Prefer mobile-first approach, in your case you should use a media breakpoint up:

```
.width-50 {
  // mobile css
}
@media (min-width: 500px){
.width-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

}